# Adding a list of a key value pair to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to be able to give a key-value pair list as a parameter in a function, and then add this list to a dictionary, (I also want to control, if the key already exists in the dictionary) how can I do this? Maybe with a for each loop, but Add() function takes 2 arguments.

```
   public void func(List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> pairs)
    {
        foreach ( var pair in pairs)
        {
            dictionary.Add(pair); // this is not working
        }
    }
```

Comment: *I also want to control, if the key already exists in the dictionary* - seems to be an incomplete statement - missing "then" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot straight add a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` to a dictionary, you need to add as a key and a value:

```
dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

If you want to overwrite an existing key with a new value, or insert the new key/value (an upsert operation):

```
dictionary[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
```

If you only want to add new key/value pairs (do not disturb/overwrite existing data), you can check if the key exists first:

```
if(!dict.ContainsKey(pair.Key)) dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

Or, if you have it available in your version of .net, you can TryAdd:

```
dict.TryAdd(pair.Key, pair.Value) //returns false and does not add if the key exists
```

In either of these latter two (`ContainsKey` returning `true` if the items exists, or `TryAdd` returning `false` if the item exists) you can use that boolean to decide what to do - merging the data in the dictionary already with the data in the incoming item for example

Answer (score 1):

The `Dictionary` does not have `AddRange` method, so you can't eliminate the loop from your code.

As for `KeyValuePair`, then, again, the `Dictionary` does not have ready-to-use overload for this, but you have at least the following options

1. Use `Add` method with manual decomposition: `dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);`
2. Create extension method that will handle `KeyValuePair`s

   ```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,
                                             KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> value)
        {
            dict.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
        }
    }
   ```

   Usage: `dictionary.Add(pair);`

To handle "key already exists" case, you can use `dictionary.ContainsKey` or just catching exception throwed by `Add` method (choose what fit best depending on the frequency of duplicated cases and you control flow)

Answer (score 1):

You need to deconstruct the `KeyValuePair` down and add it from there.

```
void func(Dictionary<string,int> dictionary, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> pairs)
{
    foreach (var (key, value) in pairs)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key,value);
    }
}
```